# Encrypted partition mount letter problem with TrueCrypt

Tags: windows, truecrypt

I am using TrueCrypt to mount an encrypted partition when I log on to my Windows computer. However it seems that TrueCrypt doesn't consistently mount the partition under the same drive letter every time.

How can I make sure an encrypted partition is mounted under the same volume letter each time?

Comment: Well I finally figured out that if I click on the drive that I want it to mount do on the TrueCrypt application window then Auto-Mount Devices it will mount the drive on whichever blank drive slot I selected. My mind went blank and I made a very simple error... hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have in the past used truecrypt on C: and D:, with D: set to automount on boot
(iirc it was saved as a 'system favorite' partition, or something like that.)

All I had to do was make sure D: was not 'cluttered' by some other storage device (ie cd/dvd/anything else). I manually changed the drive letters for my other storage devices to higher letters (ie J-P for local CD/DVD/HDD, U-Z for mapped drives) and then they did not try to steal 'D:'

Comment: I did this for my external HDs. Every HD had its own letter so it doesnt matter what port/order i connected them. I'd always know what letter to access what drive